# Lock Master Log Position in Master-Master replication

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master

I have two servers connected via private IPs. Replication is partially working, however the problem I'm running into is when I change the `MASTER_LOG_POS` on Server B using Server A's `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` command, Server A changes the log position immediately after.

Is there any way to stop MySQL from changing this position everytime? I just want them to sit still!

Below is what Server A's master status is currently. It'll increase (seemingly randomly) to something like `1583` if I try to apply that log position on Server B.

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |     1451 | db1,db2,db3  |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Why are you expecting that number to stay fixed on the master? Isn't it supposed to change pretty much constantly if there's write activity?

Comment: @Mat This is a brand new setup with no activity. Server B's position stayed the same after connecting and replication works perfect. Unfortunately only one way!

Comment: I suggest using `mysqlbinlog` tool to peek into what's being written to the binlog file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following method

> Flush tables with read lock on master(It will lock the master)
>   show master status
>   use this position accordingly in change master to command
>   unlock tables(It will unlock master)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Locking the `MASTER` on each did indeed keep the log position still.